# Find average of all columns of matrix filtered on last column

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm new to numpy.  I have an Nx4 matrix and I want to find the average of each column when the last column equals 1 for instance.  In matlab I would do something like `mean1 = mean(data[column 4] == 1)`.  This would return a matrix (or vector) with the mean of the columns, with the mean of column 4 being equal to 1.  I can't find any specific documentation that specifies how to handle this.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953111/numpy-how-to-filter-matrix-lines) shows how to filter the matrix, but I shouldn't have to reassign the matrix to a new variable, doubling storage size.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#make artificial data to match problem
data = np.random.random((100,4))
print( id(data) )
data[:,3] = data[:,3] < 0.5
print( id(data) )  #same object (memory location)
#get the filter
dfilter = data[:,3].astype(np.bool_)
#find the means
means = data[dfilter].mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did: `dfilter = data[:, 3] = data[:, 3] == 1` `mean1 = data[dfilter].mean(0)`

Comment: I needed artificial data to illustrate.  You can just do `data[data[:,3]==1].mean(0)`.

Comment: The variable method works best for this case.  I'm doing a machine learning exercise, so I have to use the filter for more than just the mean.  Just out of curiosity, does this build a matrix of pointers in the backend, or does it make an entirely new copy of the matrix?

Comment: If you mean the step `data[:,3] = data[:,3] < 0.5`, this does not build a new matrix.  I'll edit the code above to clarify this.